# Run hangs when "Attaching" to simulator

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

XCode 4.2.1 on Lion. All was fine, and XCode started hanging with "Attaching..." when running in the simulator.
I've read and tried ALL (I mean ALL!) other posts, but no success.

What is the root cause of this?
Anyone got a real solution?

Comment: Mind adding links to the posts you've tried? Otherwise you're likely to get the same responses.

Answer (score 2):

Procduct---> Edit Scheme --->Run *.app--->Info--->Debgugger, Change "LLDB" to "GDB"

Answer (score 1):

Try rebooting your machine. Sometimes the process get hung up and Xcode can see them and won't go any further because there is a pending process. Rebooting should take care of this.

To avoid this in the future, make sure you are pressing the STOP button after testing your apps, and try to only run 1 process at a time, dont leave the simulator running with an attached process and then try to run the app on your device.